# switch to modal view by clicking on tableview cell (newbie)

Tags: objective-c, ios, modalviewcontroller, segue

I know this is a simple question, but I can't find the answer. So how can I modally switch to a new view by selecting a `UITableViewCell`?

I know that I can use something like this code:

```
if (cell.isSelected)
    {
         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"someSegue" sender:self];
    }
```

I must check if this cell is Selected for some period of time and because of that I don't know where in my `UITableViewController` I should use this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to implement the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method.  This will be called when you select a row of your table view.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"someSegue" sender:self];
}
```

More details can be found in the [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html)